# how to raise events from C++ code and call handlers in C# code on another process?

Tags: c#, c++, wcf

I have been trying to do some reading on how to communicate best, and it appears that the way to communicate between non-related processes running code in different languages is usually through the use of "named pipes."

it seems like in C# you would normally use WCF while setting some bindings to make use of named pipes.  However, in C++, should i just directly create a named pipe or is there some framework/library that I should use to create named pipes?

Also, what alternative options do I have to create events in C++ that a C# application can hear?

Answer (score 1):

There are a [number of IPC mechanisms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to choose from in Windows.

Having evaluated a number of them, its really a case of deciding which one has the least disadvantages for your use case. I've used named pipes for a C# to C++ messaging system, and I'm still not sure I made the right choice.

That said, if you are *just* looking at signalling events (and don't need to include state) a [shared mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Mutex(v=vs.100).aspx) might be a lightweight alternative.

EDIT: I meant to say that if you do choose named pipes you'll need to use a custom solution. Using WCF would mean reverse engineering the WCF messaging format and reimplementing it in C++.